# stability of fixed points of μxcosx

Tags: analysis, dynamical-systems

Ι have the function Gμ(χ) = μxcosx with an approximation of μ=1+ε^2 (ε small).
I am asked to find the stability of its fixed points xk (not the 0 one)using these 2 hints :
a) taylor approximation of xk= 2πk +/- sq.root(2) * ε + Ο(ε^2)
b)taylor approximation of cos(xk) = 1-1/2 ε^2 + Ο(ε^3)

I know that in order to find the stability of xk I have to calculate the first derivative of Gμ at xk and find for which k its absolute value is less than 1( or bigger it does not really matter)

Ηere are the steps I have followed

1. I have calculated the fixed points of Gμ(χ) which are 2kπ+arcos(1/μ) & 2κπ - arcos(1/μ).
2. I have proven both hints regarding the taylor approximations of xk & cos(xk).
3. I am trying to calculate with a "smart" way the first derivative of Gμ at the points xk and try to come up with a " normal" discussable inequality for k. However, I am entering a big loop of weird operations/calculations, so I am wondering how right my last step it is ... and if it's right how can I simplify my expression so I will be able to solve the inequality | Gμ'(χκ)| <1 for k ?

Here are two pictures of my last step working proccess.
[picture 1 of my working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srA7z.jpg)
[picture 2 of my working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EblvY.jpg)